# redirect to same page after changing store front+ magento2

Tags: redirect

When I go a product page and change the store(english,danish) etc , it if redirecting to homepage of that store. I need to be in the same page. Could anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file,

```
/app/design/frontend/{theme company}/{theme name}/Magento_Store/templates/switch/ languages.phtml
```

Change the line:-

```
<a href="<?php echo $_lang->getBaseUrl(); ?>" data-post1='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>' <?php echo $flag ?>>
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></a>
```

**instead**

```
<a href="<?php echo  $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false) ?>" data-post1='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>' <?php echo $flag ?>>
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></a>
```